# Unable to load content from File URI

Tags: android, file, imageview, mime-types

Hi i have a media file URI and i want to determine the mimetype and invoke appropriate activity in a generic way, Following is my code.

```
mediaUri = Uri.parse(filePath);

String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();
viewMediaIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(mediaUri,mimeType);
viewMediaIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

Now the problem is few of the file uris are not working. But the same uri if converted to http uri and load from browser they are working fine. or any other app is able to load them,

Sample URIs which doesn't work
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Image/001.JPG`
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over the horizon.mp3`

Error:

```
09-30 12:07:44.531: I/System.out(26771): Item Selected: file:///storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Image/001.JPG`
09-30 12:07:44.531: I/System.out(26771): mime type: null`
09-30 12:07:44.534: D/AndroidRuntime(26771): Shutting down VM`
09-30 12:07:44.534: W/dalvikvm(26771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e50ac8)`
09-30 12:07:44.545: E/AndroidRuntime(26771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
09-30 12:07:44.545: E/AndroidRuntime(26771): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Image/001.JPG flg=0x14000000 }`
09-30 12:07:44.545: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)`
09-30 12:07:44.545: E/AndroidRuntime(26771):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)`
```

Comment: explain "not working"

Comment: I have updated the edit with error log. Basically it doesn't find the mime type and hence fails to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
String mimeType;
if (uri.toString().lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
String ext = uri.toString().substring(
    uri.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext.toLowerCase());
} else {
mimeType = null;
}
```

With this method i'm able to get the correct mimetype and load works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the extension in a more elegant way simply by calling the `getFileExtensionFromUrl(url)` method on `MimeTypeMap` like this

```
public static String getMimeType(String url)
  {
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
  }
```

Comment: Then just set it to lower case as you do in your snippet, my post was about avoiding messing with string indexes by using `getFileExtensionFromUrl(url)`